# date comparison returning incorrect results

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to return records that fall under a specific range but it seems that the wrong records are returned, this issue does not occur when I opt to use the `$lt` condition alone.

Below is the returned json

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a5528c471872a00ee77731d"
},
"histories": [
    {
        "created": "2017-09-21T08:24:18.716+0100",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "status",
                "fieldtype": "jira",
                "fieldId": "status",
                "from": "10007",
                "fromString": "With Testing",
                "to": "10012",
                "toString": "Completed"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "created": "2017-10-27T15:10:58.179+0100",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "status",
                "fieldtype": "jira",
                "fieldId": "status",
                "from": "10007",
                "fromString": "With Testing",
                "to": "10012",
                "toString": "Completed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Below is the aggregate pipeline being used with commented out attempts.

```
'pipeline' => [
[
    '$match' => [
        'histories.created' => [
            '$gte' => '2017-09-28T00:00:00Z+0100',
            '$lt' => '2017-10-04T00:00:00Z+0100' 
            //'$gte' => '2017-09-28T00:00:00Z',
            //'$lt' => '2017-10-04T00:00:00Z' 
            //'$gte' => '2017-09-28',
            //'$lt' => '2017-10-04' 
        ]
    ]
]
]
```

The mongo collection I'm querying has no `histories.created` with a value between `2017-09-28 to 2017-10-04` so I should an empty json from the above query instead of one record

```
{}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I tried converting the date strings in to `UTCDateTime` objects but I still get the same results

I'm using mongodb with php

Comment: we don't know what records you want, or how your getting them, this is unanswerable

Comment: You are querying for array values, so in case if there is atleast one element where created value falls between `$gte` and `$lt`, the whole histories array is returned. What is your expected json response ?

Comment: @rtfm it's in the pipeline, I want all records that has a `histories.created` value that is between 2017-09-28 to 2017-10-04. I'll add an expected output if that helps

Comment: @Veeram Sure, but the dates in the example output doesn't fall between 2017-09-28 to 2017-10-04

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about elemMatch in array comparison. This will compare both the gt and lt comparison against same element. Try `[
    '$match' => [
        'histories' => ['$elemMatch' => ['created' => [
            '$gte' => '2017-09-28T00:00:00Z+0100',
            '$lt' => '2017-10-04T00:00:00Z+0100' 
        ] ]
    ] ]
]`. The query you have also compares query condition on different element meaning it will return entire array if two different elements satisfy each of criteria.

Comment: @Veeram Thank you, tested and it seems to work